# Locating xpath of a radio button based on the text adjacent to it

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<input id="lblProductName+Modem promo +default" 
    class="cmpAvailableSingleSelectProduct-radioButton" 
    type="radio" 
    onclick="cmpAvailableSSProductRadioToggleHandler(event, this,'Line_0.DSL.modemcre_s021403', 'false');" 
    name="defaultLine_0.DSL.modemcre_s021403Modem promo">
```

The above type is a radio button where the id is based on the next div tag.

`<div class="cmpAvailableSingleSelectProduct-lblProductName">Modem promo - 100 </div>`

I do know what will be the name (Modem promo - 100) inside the div class. But I'd like to click on the radio button adjacent to that. I will be getting the value of "Modem promo - 100" as a string. I'd like to compare with the text and click on the adjacent radio button.

Please help me on how to write xpath or finding the webElement. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to locate radio button based on the next div element, try this locator `//div[contains(@class, 'cmpAvailableSingleSelectProduct-lblProductName']/preceding-sibling::input/` Hope it helps!

Comment: But I have multiple cmpAvailableSingleSelectProduct. I just need a way to locate the element based on the value inside the div which is **Modem promo - 100**

Comment: `//div[contains(@class, 'cmpAvailableSingleSelectProduct-lblProductName') and text()='Modem promo - 100 ']/preceding-sibling::input/` - try this

Comment: But the **Modem promo - 100** is a string value that is stored in the string **ValueOfPromo** . The Promo value will be a dynamic value based on what the value is returned in ValueOfPromo string. Can we mention the xpath as text() = ValueOfPromo??

Comment: Yes! You can use String variable instead of hardcoded string.

Comment: Thanks Harish. Will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You should try using xpath as below :-

```
String ValueOfPromo = "Modem promo - 100";

String xpath = "(.//div[contains(.,'" +ValueOfPromo+ "')]/preceding::input)[1]";

driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. Will check and let you know.